# Python: Function does not seem to return any value

Tags: python, function, compare

This is the compare function:

```
def compare(a, b):

    if a > b:
        return 1

    elif a == b:
        return 0

    else:
        return -1


a=int(input('Enter first number here:'))

b=int(input('enter second number here:'))

compare(a,b)
```

---

when I run it, it prompts the user for a and b but after they are entered the program doesn't do anything it returns none. 
Why does this happen?

Comment: because you never print it out. Try `print(compare(a,b))`

Comment: Perhaps you tried this in the interactive interpreter? In the interactive shell, any expression that you execute that doesn't produce `None` is *echoed*. But that only happens in the interactive interpreter, because for real production scripts, you don't want everything to be echoed all the time. You need to explicitly write out stuff you want to appear on the screen instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` keyword returns data back. If you want to see the output, use `print`.
Try

```
print(compare(a, b))
```

The compare function will `return` the number, `print` prints it to console / IDLE

Comment: ok i will try that thank you. when i tried to make the function using the python shell the return keyword did print the number after it. why is that?

Comment: The return keyword is used in a function when you want to output values. print is used to display text into the console.

Comment: ok thank you for your time, i tried print(compare(a,b)) and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need a print statement.

```
def compare(a, b):
    if a > b:
        return 1

    elif a == b:
        return 0

    else:
        return -1

a = int(input('Enter first number here:'))
b = int(input('Enter second number here:'))

print(compare(a, b)) # use this line if using python 3
# print compare(a, b) # use this line if using python 2
```

Comment: They are almost certainly using Python 3, so your Python 2 `print` statement will result in a syntax error.